# AngularJS two repeating list

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have two lists, mainTags and selectedTags. What I need to do is once a tag in mainTags is clicked, I need to move this item to the selectedTags list, and remove it from the mainTags list. I wrote the code below, but I don't know why it doesn't work. I'm new to AngularJS so I can't find where the problem is myself.

```js
$scope.selectedTags = { tags: [] };  
$scope.Main.tags.setTags(function(tag) {
 $scope.selectedTags.tags.push({ id: tag.id, name: tag.name });
 });
```

```html
<button type="button" ng-repeat="tag in SuggestedMain.tags track by tag.id"
                      ng-click="setTags(tag);">{{ ::tag.name }}</button>


<button ng-show="selectedTags.tags.length"
        ng-repeat="tag in selectedTags.tags track by tag.id">{{ ::tag.name }}</button>
```

Comment: Can you show rest of controller code and view as well..

Comment: Also what exact error are getting right now?

Comment: Your code doesn't remove the tag from the main tags, and it creates a copy of the tag rather than just moving it to the selected tags. We also have no idea at all about what actually happens with the tiny snippet of code you shared, so it's basically impossible to help.

Comment: *'doesn't work'* doesn't tell us what you expect to happen or what is happening different from expectations. we can't help you with a problem when you don't identify what that problem is